# How to get exact solution for determinant in mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra

I am currently trying to program in mathematica, my issue is that the program is not solving for the exact value of the determinant in comparison to matlab. Code given below, where a and x are variables. Any tips on how i can get the exact value? Thanks in advance. I was not able to also insert the determinant i got from mathematica for comparison.

```
v = {{-a*0.04 - 0.015 - x, 0.25, -a*0.9, 
0.94*0.03}, {0.015, -4*a*0.04 - 0.25 - x, -4*a*0.06, 
0.06*0.03}, {a*0.04, 4*a*0.04, a*0.9 + 4*a*0.06 - 0.1428 - x, 
0}, {0, 0, 0.1428, -0.03 - x}};
```

Det[v]

This is what i get when calculating the determinant in matlab:

Syms a x

```
v=[-a*0.04-0.015-x,0.25,-a*0.9,0.94*0.03;0.015,-4*a*0.04-0.25-x,-4*a*0.06,0.06*0.03;a*0.04,4*a*0.04,a*0.9+4*a*0.06-0.1428-x,0;0,0,0.1428,-0.03-x];
```

det(v)

```
- 0.1472*a^2*x^2 - 0.0035*a^2*x - 0.9400*a*x^3 - 0.2893*a*x^2 - 0.0063*a*x + x^4 + 0.4378*x^3 + 0.0501*x^2 + 0.0011*x
```

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. What does Matlab give you?

Comment: "the program is not solving for the exact value of the determinant in comparison to matlab" Are you saying Matlab gives "exact" value for `det(v)` above? How? can you show the Matlab code you used?

Comment: I tried updating with the matlabcode included hope this helps apologies for the bad formatting

Comment: Try `Det[v]//Chop` to replace small approximate numbers that are close to zero with exactly zero.

Comment: Perfect that solves it, thank you so much.

Comment: `expr = Det[Rationalize@v] // N[#, {6, 5}] &`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
Det[v // Rationalize[#, 0] &]
```

to evaluate symbolically!

Comparison with matlab-result would require values for `x,a`